# how to get data from json file using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am getting data from json file to display in a table, but first time only i got data from getdata() next time i got following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined       Controller.js:95

$http return value is fine, i got all data from json file first time, next time i could not get data from getdata().
getData() function is not working properly, it is working only first time, next time i could not get data.

how to solve this issue.

controller.js

```
    var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable', 'claimApp']); 
    app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, appFactory,$http) {
   $scope.datasets = ["1", "2", "3"];
   $scope.dataset = "1"; 
   var data1 = [];
var data2 = []; 
var data3 = []; 
$scope.totalCnt = function () {
    return window.document.getElementById("tablesort").getElementsByTagName("TR").length - 1;
}; 

var getData = function () {  
    if ($scope.dataset == "1") { 
         $http.get('json/json0.json').success(function(data) {
           data1 = data; 
          });  
        return data1; 
    } else if ($scope.dataset == "2") { 
           $http.get('json/json1.json').success(function(data) {
           data2= data;   
          });  
           return data2; 
    } else if ($scope.dataset == "3") { 
               $http.get('json/json2.json').success(function(data) {
           data3= data;   
          });  
          return data3; 
    } 
};
$scope.$watch("dataset", function () { 
    $("#tablesort").fadeOut('slow', function () { 
        $scope.tableParams.reload();
        $scope.tableParams.page(1); 
        $("#tablesort").fadeIn('slow');   
    }); 
});
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1, // show first page
    count: 10, // count per page
    sorting: {
        name: 'asc' // initial sorting
    }
}, {
    total: function () { 
        return getData().length;
        console.info("==="+getData().length);
    }, // length of data
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        var filteredData = getData(); 
        console.info("filteredData"+filteredData);<!--i could not get this data second time only it is working first time-->
        var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
            $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
            filteredData; 
        var lastPage = (1 + Math.floor((orderedData.length - 1) / params.count())); 
        $("#lastpage").html(lastPage); 
        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

    },
    $scope: {
        $data: {}
    } 
}); 
 });
```

Comment: Instead of `data1 = data;` use `$scope.data1 = data;` and remove return statement. Same with `data2, data3`

Answer (score 0):

according to the doc

```
Request transformations:

If the data property of the request configuration object contains an object, serialize it         into JSON format.
Response transformations:

If XSRF prefix is detected, strip it (see Security Considerations section below).
If JSON response is detected, deserialize it using a JSON parser.
```

so use in your response

```
$http.get('json/json0.json').success(function(data) {
       data1 = JSON.parse(data); 
      });
```

**EDIT**

```
var getData = function () {  
if ($scope.dataset == "1") { 

     $http.get('json/json0.json').success(function(data) {
       $scope.response = data; 
      });  
} else if ($scope.dataset == "2") { 

       $http.get('json/json1.json').success(function(data) {
       $scope.response = data; 
      });  

} else if ($scope.dataset == "3") { 

           $http.get('json/json2.json').success(function(data) {
       $scope.response = data; 
      });  

} 
return $scope.response;
};
```

Comment: whare i want to use this?

Comment: my json data like this:    [

                  {
                      "claim": "One",
                      "ta": 43,
                      "assy": "nae1",
                      "sa": "SA1",
                      "pity": "Prty1",
                      "acn": [{
                          "action1": "Acon1"
                      }, {
                          "action2": "Actn2"
                      }]
                  }]

Comment: console.log(data) what do you have in it ?

Comment: tell me what you have in log of console

Comment: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: this is not working second time: var filteredData = getData();  
    alert(filteredData);

Comment: understand my QA.all data coming from json file, that is no problem, but i could not get the return data by this getData(). so how to get the return data into the function:var filteredData = getData(); alert(filteredData);

Comment: can you tell me now ?

Comment: NB: instead of getData, you can use $scope.response

Comment: i find the mistake, that loading problem.